# Produce new columns based on priority list

Tags: r, dataframe

Having a priority list like:

```
Google: High priority
Yahoo: medium priority
Microsoft: low priority
```

from a binary dataframe like the following:

```
> df  <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), Google = c(1,1,0), Yahoo = c(1,1,1), Microsoft = c(0,1,1))
> df
  id Google Yahoo Microsoft
1  1      1     1         0
2  2      1     1         1
3  3      0     1         1
```

How is it possible to produce a new dataframe in which the columns are the same but depending on the priority only the column with the highest priority which has the 1 keep it and the other take 0 in every row?

Example of expected outcome:

```
> df  <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), Google = c(1,1,0), Yahoo = c(0,0,1), Microsoft = c(0,0,0))
> df
  id Google Yahoo Microsoft
1  1      1     0         0
2  2      1     0         0
3  3      0     1         0
```

Comment: Try `df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {i1 <- which(x==max(x))[1]; replace(x, (i1+1):length(x), 0)}))`

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
mc <- max.col(df[-1], ties.method = 'first')
df[-1] <- 0
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), mc + 1)] <- 1
```

gives:

> ```
> > df
>   id Google Yahoo Microsoft
> 1  1      1     0         0
> 2  2      1     0         0
> 3  3      0     1         0
> ```

If the company columns are not in the priority order, you can change that with:

```
priority <- c('Google',"Yahoo",'Microsoft')
df <- df[, c(1, match(priority, names(df)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `apply` function:

```
 df[-1]= t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x)`[<-`(x,-which.max(x),0)))
 df
  id Google Yahoo Microsoft
1  1      1     0         0
2  2      1     0         0
3  3      0     1         0
```